# Is there a way to retrieve Sitecore Forms Field Visibility on Server Side

Tags: sitecore-forms

Using Sitecore Forms sc 10.0 , I am trying to identify whether a field is hidden or part of a hidden section from Server side FormSubmitContext Fields (in SubmitActions).
These fields are shown/hidden on forms using forms conditions.

The Posted Field Context has the conditions info but not the state of the action to know the field visibility whether it is hidden/disabled.

Is there a way to retrieve Sitecore Forms Field Visibility on Server Side ?

Comment: I am not sure about this option but instead, you can take a hidden field on the form, and from your script, you can set that hidden field value to true false based on the change event of your required field, then in your submit action you will get hidden field value automatically that you can use.

Comment: I think you need to do your own server evaluation, similar like on client side: sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/form.conditions.js